# Generalisation of Kapitza-like method for particles in rapidly oscillating fields to more dimensions

Tags: classical-mechanics, perturbation-theory

On [page 93 of *Mechanics* by Landau and Lifshitz](https://ia600307.us.archive.org/11/items/Mechanics_541/LandauLifshitz-Mechanics.pdf), they discuss a general derivation of Kapitza's method. At the end of their derivation, they say that their results can *easily* be generalised to any number of degrees of freedom, and they quote the following result (see link for context):
$$U_{\text{eff}}= U+\frac{1}{2\omega^2}\sum_{ik}a_{ik}^{-1}\overline{f_if_k}.$$
I spent a few hours trying to reproduce the result, but always got stuck. This is what I have tried so far:

---

Let's assume the kinetic energy of the system has the form:
\begin{equation} \label{eq:kinener}
 T = \frac{1}{2}\sum_k \sum_j t_{jk}\dot{q_j}(t)\dot{q_k}(t)
\end{equation}
where the sum is over all the degrees of freedom.
The Euler-Lagrange equations lead to
\begin{equation} \label{bwv}
 \sum_k t_{jk}\ddot{q_k}(t) = -\frac{\partial U(\mathbf{q}(t))}{\partial q_j} + f^{(j)}(\mathbf{q}(t)), \,\,\,\,\,\,\, 0 \leq j \leq n,
\end{equation}
where I added a "generalised force disturbance" $f^{(j)}$ . Let's now separate the motion into fast and slow components:
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{q}(t) = \mathbf{Q}(t) + \boldsymbol{\xi}(t),
\end{equation} where $\boldsymbol{\xi}(t)$ corresponds to the small oscillations.

Using this, and expanding to first order around the smooth component, I get:

\begin{multline} \label{eq:bwvt}
 \sum_k t_{jk}(\ddot{Q_k}+ \ddot{\xi_k}) = -\frac{\partial  U(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial q_j} - \sum_k \frac{\partial^2 U(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial q_k\partial q_j} \xi_k \\
 + f^{(j)}(\mathbf{Q},t) + \sum_k\xi_k\frac{\partial f^{(j)}(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial q_k},
\end{multline}

We now fix $\boldsymbol{\xi}(t)$ by
\begin{equation} \label{eq:choiceXi}
    \sum_k t_{jk}\ddot{\xi_k}(t) = f^{(j)}(\mathbf{Q},t).
\end{equation}
Integrating, I regard $\mathbf{Q}$ constant and discard all integration constants:
\begin{equation}
    \sum_k t_{jk} \xi_k(t) = -\frac{1}{\omega^2}f^{(j)}(\mathbf{Q},t) \implies \xi_k = -\frac{1}{\omega^2}\sum_j t_{kj}^{-1}f^{(j)}(\mathbf{Q},t), 
\end{equation}
where $t_{kj}^{-1}$ are the inverse matrix elements. Filling this all in and averaging:
\begin{align*}
    \sum_k t_{jk} \ddot{Q}_k &= -\frac{\partial U(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial Q_j} + \sum_k \langle \xi_k \frac{\partial f^{(j)}(\mathbf{Q},t)}{\partial Q_k} \rangle \\ &= -\frac{\partial U(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial Q_j} -\frac{1}{\omega^2} \sum_k\sum_i  t_{ki}^{-1} \langle f^{(j)}(\mathbf{Q},t) \frac{\partial f^{(j)}(\mathbf{Q},t)}{\partial Q_k} \rangle \\ &=-\frac{\partial U(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial Q_j} -\frac{1}{2\omega^2} \sum_k\sum_i  t_{ki}^{-1} \langle  \frac{\partial f^{(j)2}(\mathbf{Q},t)}{\partial Q_k}\rangle 
\end{align*}
... this is where I'm stuck...

Could it be that the Landau and Lifshitz result is just wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the answer being sought is an effective potential energy, we're clearly dealing with conservative forces, including the forces $f^{(j)}$.  The key observation needed to finish solving this problem is that for conservative forces,
$$\frac{\partial f^{(j)}}{\partial q_k}=\frac{\partial f^{(k)}}{\partial q_j}   \ \ .$$
This result easily follows from a conservative force always being the gradient of some potential energy:
$$\frac{\partial f^{(j)}}{\partial q_k}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial q_k}\frac{\partial U_{fast}}{\partial q_j}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial q_j}\frac{\partial U_{fast}}{\partial q_k}=\frac{\partial f^{(k)}}{\partial q_j}   \ \ .$$
You also had the issue of getting tripped up toward the end by $j$ being used as the summation variable in your expression for $\xi_k$ .  To avoid that problem, I'll rewrite the equation for $\xi_k$ using $i$ as the summation variable instead of $j$:
$$\xi_k = -\frac{1}{\omega^2}\sum_i t_{ki}^{-1}f^{(i)}(\mathbf{Q},t)\ \ .$$
Starting with the first equation in your last set of equations, we then have
\begin{align*}
    \sum_k t_{jk} \ddot{Q}_k &= -\frac{\partial U(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial Q_j} + \sum_k \left\langle \xi_k \frac{\partial f^{(j)}(\mathbf{Q},t)}{\partial Q_k} \right\rangle
\\ &= -\frac{\partial U(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial Q_j} -\frac{1}{\omega^2} \sum_k\sum_i  t_{ki}^{-1} \left\langle f^{(i)}(\mathbf{Q},t) \frac{\partial f^{(j)}(\mathbf{Q},t)}{\partial Q_k} \right\rangle
\\ &= -\frac{\partial U(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial Q_j} -\frac{1}{\omega^2} \sum_k\sum_i  t_{ki}^{-1} \left\langle f^{(i)}(\mathbf{Q},t) \frac{\partial f^{(k)}(\mathbf{Q},t)}{\partial Q_j} \right\rangle
\\ &= -\frac{\partial U(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial Q_j} -\frac{1}{2\omega^2} \sum_i\sum_k t_{ik}^{-1} \left[ \left\langle f^{(i)}(\mathbf{Q},t) \frac{\partial f^{(k)}(\mathbf{Q},t)}{\partial Q_j} \right\rangle + \left\langle \frac{\partial f^{(i)}(\mathbf{Q},t)}{\partial Q_j} f^{(k)}(\mathbf{Q},t)  \right\rangle \right]\ \ ,
\end{align*}

where the last step uses the fact that $t_{ik}^{-1}$ is symmetric (because $t_{ik}$ is symmetric).  Using the chain rule and linearity, we then have

\begin{align*}
\sum_k t_{jk} \ddot{Q}_k &= -\frac{\partial U(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial Q_j} -\frac{1}{2\omega^2} \sum_i\sum_k t_{ik}^{-1} \left\langle f^{(i)}(\mathbf{Q},t) \frac{\partial f^{(k)}(\mathbf{Q},t)}{\partial Q_j} + \frac{\partial f^{(i)}(\mathbf{Q},t)}{\partial Q_j} f^{(k)}(\mathbf{Q},t)  \right\rangle
\\ &= -\frac{\partial U(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial Q_j} -\frac{1}{2\omega^2} \sum_i\sum_k t_{ik}^{-1} \left\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial Q_j} f^{(i)}(\mathbf{Q},t)  f^{(k)}(\mathbf{Q},t)  \right\rangle
\\ &= -\frac{\partial U(\mathbf{Q})}{\partial Q_j} -\frac{\partial}{\partial Q_j}\frac{1}{2\omega^2} \sum_i\sum_k t_{ik}^{-1} \left\langle  f^{(i)}(\mathbf{Q},t)  f^{(k)}(\mathbf{Q},t)  \right\rangle
\\ &= -\frac{\partial}{\partial Q_j} U_{eff}(\mathbf{Q})\ \ ,
\end{align*}

where

$$U_{eff}(\mathbf{Q})=U(\mathbf{Q})+\frac{1}{2\omega^2} \sum_i\sum_k t_{ik}^{-1} \left\langle  f^{(i)}(\mathbf{Q},t)  f^{(k)}(\mathbf{Q},t)  \right\rangle$$